# Is there a standard syntax for pagination for an API?

Tags: api

We're having a bit of a debate between specifying the page number vs. row number, along with rows per page. E.g. to get rows 21-40 it could be either

```
page=2&rows=20
```

or

```
offset=21&limit=20
```

I know this is a bit of an opinion question, but any standards or best practices out there?

Comment: Please remember to read tag descriptions before using them. [tag:api] is not supposed to be used on its own.

Answer (score 0):

This would really depend on the source and consumer of your data but, for comparison, [REST best practices](http://www.restapitutorial.com/media/RESTful_Best_Practices-v1_1.pdf) (warning, PDF!) specify `offset` and `limit` parameters, as in your second example.

I think the document claims this is simpler if pages may contain different numbers of rows; your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously both work, but I've seen page more often than not. From a UI perspective, users may not know what offset means.. but they have an expectation from changing the page field. Also, if you use page, you should restrict what values limit should be. The point of pagination is to ensure that the backend doesn't send a ton of data back to the UI, so giving only a few options (or choosing for the user) would achieve that.